# Subscribe to blocks in Solana (JSON RPC API)

Tags: json, api, block, rpc, solana

I have been reading old blocks from the solana JSON RPC API (using python), but now I am trying to subscribe to the block production on the solana network (to get up live updates).

I tried to pull updates through the RPC API using

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": "1", "method": "blockSubscribe", "params": ["all"]}
```

This doesn't work, with response: `'code': -32601, 'message': 'Method not found'`

Looking at the [docs.solana.com](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#blocksubscribe---unstable-disabled-by-default) info, it states that:

> This subscription is unstable and only available if the validator was
> started with the `--rpc-pubsub-enable-block-subscription` flag. The
> format of this subscription may change in the future

I assume this means I need to run `solana-test-validator --rpc-pubsub-enable-block-subscription`, but this just returns:

```
error: Found argument '--rpc-pubsub-enable-block-subscription' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
        Did you mean --rpc-port?

USAGE:
    solana-test-validator --ledger <DIR> --rpc-port <PORT>
```

I can't seem to find any more information on how to subscribe to blocks using the RPC.
Any ideas or help with what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the validator has to run `--rpc-pubsub-enable-block-subscription`. For mainnet-beta usage, it is recommended to either find a private rpc with this enabled or have your own. Please note though, the method is marked currently as unstable.

It looks like `rpc-pubsub-enable-block-subscription` is not available on the test validator. You can find the full command list [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/validator/src/bin/solana-test-validator.rs).

Answer (score 0):

This subscription is unstable and only available if the validator was started with the --rpc-pubsub-enable-block-subscription flag. The format of this subscription may change in the future

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).